# How to Fill Gap Between Steel Beam and Concrete Pillar?

Tags: concrete, foundation, beam

I have a Concrete Foundation Pillar that is 5/8th of an inch too short. What filler materials are appropriate when a steel I Beam will be resting on it? Can I use mortar, or is steel more appropriate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mortar is not really structural, I would go with steel, perhaps half-inch plate and some washers

Comment: Why 1/2” plate and washers over a 5/8 steel plate?

Comment: sure, 5/8 if you can get it. or flat bar instead of plate.

Comment: Non-Shrink Structural Grout is an option.  Really even wood in the correct orientation is fine.  The crush strength of wood is quite high.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger The appropriateness of wood for something like this can vary depending on conditions and the type of wood. You don't want your structural support rotting away, after all.